# Move component in a div to another div when clicked in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Let's say I have one component that only holds an image and two divs, one holding the componenet, laid out as such:

[image]

Upon being clicked, the component will move into the other div
[image]

Then when the component is clicked again, it moves back to its original spot, like such:
[image]

What would the logic be in order to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated especially with code examples.

Comment: It depends on a few factors, and it'd be easier for the community to answer if you provide a code example to show what you've attempted and how it does or doesn't accomplish your goal.

Comment: Conceptually in React workflow, at the bare minimum, you'd probably want to set a `state` variable to track whether or not a target component is clicked `on` or `off`. Then conditionally render image in either of the two container components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to my codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/magical-minsky-bx681m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: in this example the h3 is still there, even if it's empty, I would advise to use a condition such as { showText1 && <h3>Img</h3> } If you don't want to show the text, you should get rid of the node. Also, you can do this with only one useState, instead of 2.